# Unable to set VBA Slicer selected property value to False

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on Excel and VBA and I am trying to figure out how to deselect various fields from my slicer and only select few.
I try to read the slicer Cache and then iterate over various items within the slicer. I am able to read the values of the items within the slicer, but i am unable to deselect them. It keeps on throwing up an "application-defined or Object-defined error" with the error code 1004.

I am sharing the code snippet i am facing difficulty with.

```
Sub SelectFiscalWeeks()

Dim slcCache As SlicerCache
Dim slcItem As SlicerItem

FalseVar = False
Application.StatusBar = "Filtering out last 13 Week's Data"

Set slcCache = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date.Fiscal_Week")

slcCache.ClearManualFilter

For Index = 1 To slcCache.SlicerCacheLevels.Count
    Worksheets("A").Cells(Index + 1, "N").Value = Index

    j = 0
    For Each slcItem In slcCache.SlicerCacheLevels(Index).SlicerItems
        Worksheets("A").Cells(j + 1, "P").Value = slcItem.Name
        j = j + 1
        slcItem.Selected = FalseVar
    Next
Next

'Set slcCache.VisibleSlicerItems = Array("[DT].[FW].&[201701]")

Set slcCache = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

In the above code I am able to read the Slicer Item names by using slcItem.Name, but I am unable to Execute either of the following statements:

```
slcItem.Selected = FalseVar
Set slcCache.VisibleSlicerItems = Array("[DT].[FW].&[201701]")
```

Executing these statements throws up an error "application-defined or Object-defined error" with the error code 1004.

I have been trying debugging for more than an hour but am unable to figure out the cause. It might be something basic, but can you please help me identify what might be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, I've been debugging for couple hours with the same problem you have.
Finally I found I should use VisibleSlicerItems instead of setting .selected to be true/false.

Try slcCache.VisibleSlicerItems = Array("[DT].[FW].&[201701]") without Set.

Here is my code as example.
Hope could help you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim si As SlicerItem
Dim list As Variant


Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_product_name")

    For Each si In sc.SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems
        If InStr(si.Value, "Boxers") > 0 Then
            'this if loop creates an Array for VisibleSlicerItems
            If IsEmpty(list) Then
                list = Array(si.Name)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve list(UBound(list) + 1)
                list(UBound(list)) = si.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next

sc.VisibleSlicerItemsList = list

End Sub
```